# How to allocate an off-heap byte buffer in a portable way?

Tags: java, java-8

Is there a way to allocate a simple off-heap byte buffer while targeting both jdk-8 and jdk-11 (i.e it's impossible to use `Unsafe` or `VarHandle`?

Current solution relies on `RandomAccessFile`, but the goal is to use only direct memory.

I'm trying `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`, but it looks like it's still limited by the heap size.

```
 * $JDK_16/bin/jshell -R-Xmx32m 
jshell> java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(33 * 1024 * 1024)
|  Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot reserve 34603008 bytes of direct buffer memory (allocated: 141, limit: 33554432)
|        at Bits.reserveMemory (Bits.java:178)
|        at DirectByteBuffer.<init> (DirectByteBuffer.java:121)
|        at ByteBuffer.allocateDirect (ByteBuffer.java:330)
|        at (#1:1)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do that require an off-heap byte buffer? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of what you are trying to do. This question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: [ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), Since (java) 1.4

Comment: `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(capacity)`

Comment: @Stephen But isn't ByteBuffer limited by heap size (Xmx) any way?

Comment: Use MappedByteBuffer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html You have to create a FileChannel and map from there to get an instance

Comment: @SwiftMango - that approach requires a file in the filesystem.  Using `allocateDirect` avoids that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to allocate an off-heap byte buffer in a portable way?

Use `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(capacity)`; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect-int-) for details.  (Also read the section at the top that explains the difference between normal and direct buffers and lists some of the caveats of using direct buffers.)

> I'm trying `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`, but it looks like it's still limited by the heap size.

It is not limited by the heap size (`-Xmx`).  It is actually limited by:

- an explicit `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=size` option or the default `MaxDirectMemorySize` value, and
- how much memory the operating system is prepared to allocate to the JVM when it asks for it.

The `java` manual page says this about the above option:

> *"By  default, the size is set to 0, meaning that the JVM chooses the size for NIO direct-buffer allocations automatically."*

How it makes that choice is liable to be Java version and OS specific, and may possibly take account of the dimensions of your hardware (or virtual machine) platform.